# How to implement deep copy feature in some smart pointer?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

unique_ptr is quite useful. However, it is not copyable. If virutal clone (deep copy) methods are provided for its pointed class, I think it will become more useful. Is it necessary or any better way to implement it? Any similar smart pointer exist in some library? Here is a version

```
template<class T>
class deep_ptr: private unique_ptr<T>
{
public:
    using unique_ptr<T>::operator *;
    using unique_ptr<T>::operator ->;
    using unique_ptr<T>::operator bool;
    using unique_ptr<T>::release;
    using unique_ptr<T>::reset;
    using unique_ptr<T>::get;

    // add (DEFAULT_CONSTRUCTOR)(MOVE_CONSTRUCTOR)(MOVE_ASSIGNMENT_METHOD) ...

    explicit deep_ptr(T* p) : unique_ptr(p) {}

    deep_ptr(deep_ptr const& r) : unique_ptr(r->clone()) {}

    deep_ptr& operator=(deep_ptrconst& r)
    { if (this != &r) reset(r->clone()); return *this; }
};
```

Juse feel it is very useful but never see similar things. ???

Comment: Can you post a few lines of code to indicate how you intend to use it?

Comment: @GuyGreer Oh my bad, I misinterpreted the question.

Comment: @GuyGreer - shared_ptr does not have deep nor shallow copy semantics. That is up to the object that it points to

Comment: @EdHeal I meant copying a shared_ptr does not copy the underlying object, which makes it a shallow copy, unless I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: If you want to copy the object what do you need the pointer for? Just pass the object around directly.

Comment: _"... However, it is not copyable"_ - Making it copyable would create a situation where two `unique_ptr`'s manage the same object. This would break the single ownership semantics of `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @GuyGreer You really need to be specific if you mean a shallow copy of the **smart pointer object** or a shallow copy of the **object pointed to by the smart pointer**. These are NOT the same things. I would not expect ``smart_ptr = smart_ptr`` to do a shallow or deep cop of the pointed-to object any more than I would expect ``object * = object *`` to do so.

Comment: To the OP's question, what exactly do you mean by 'it is not copyable'? ``unique_ptr``, by definition, is neither *Copy Assignable* nor *Copy Constructable*, since, after all, it's *unique*. Therefore ``unique_ptr A = unique_ptr(new Object)`` will of course fail. But it doesn't make any constraints on the copyability of the object is is pointing to. ``Object A = *unique_ptr(Object)`` is perfectly valid if the pointed-to object provides an ``operator=`` overload.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I am misunderstanding what you are looking for, if a class has a clone method, that should be sufficient to get what you are looking for.

Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct A
{
   virtual ~A() {}
   virtual A* clone() = 0;
};

struct B : A
{
   B(int in = 0) : x(in) {}
   B(B const& copy) : x(copy.x) {}
   virtual ~B() {std::cout << "In B::~B()\n";}

   virtual A* clone() { return new B(*this); }
   int x;
};

int main()
{
   std::unique_ptr<A> p1(new B(10));
   std::unique_ptr<A> p2(p1->clone());
   return 0;
}
```

Output from running the above program:

```
In B::~B()
In B::~B()
```

Comment: If the pointer is a member of a class which is deep-copyable. I cannot use the implict copy constructor.

Comment: @user1899020, do you mean "if the `std::unique_ptr` is a member of a class ..."??

Comment: like class A { unique_ptr<B> mB; ... } and to make A copyable, we need to write a copy constructor. If using deep_ptr, we can use compiler-provided version.

Comment: @user1899020, Unless you have lots of such classes, it is better to write a copy constructor for `A` than to derive from `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

Without a clone method (just a copy-constructor) the following should work:

```
template <typename T>
class deep_ptr
{
public:
  deep_ptr() : i_() {}

  deep_ptr(std::nullptr_t) : i_(nullptr) {}

  template <typename U>
    deep_ptr(U* u) : i_(u ? new inner_impl<U>(*u) : nullptr) {}

  ~deep_ptr() { delete i_; }

  deep_ptr(const deep_ptr& p) : i_(p.i_ ? p.i_->copy() : nullptr) {}

  deep_ptr& operator=(const deep_ptr& p)
  {
    if (!p.i_) { i_ = nullptr; }
    else { i_ = p.i_->copy(); }
  }

  deep_ptr(deep_ptr&& p) : i_(p.i_) { p.i_ = nullptr; }

  deep_ptr& operator=(deep_ptr&& p)
  {
    i_ = p.i_;
    p.i_ = nullptr;
  }

  const T* operator->() const { return get(); }

  const T* get() const
  {
    if (i_) { return *i_; }
    return nullptr;
  }

  const T& operator*() const { return *static_cast<T*>(*i_); }

  T* operator->() { return get(); }

  T* get()
  {
    if (i_) { return *i_; }
    return nullptr;
  }

  T& operator*(){ return *static_cast<T*>(*i_); }

private:
  struct inner
  { 
    virtual inner* copy() const = 0;
    virtual operator const T*() const  = 0;
    virtual operator T*() = 0;
    virtual ~inner() {}
  };

  inner* i_;

  template <typename U>
  struct inner_impl : inner
  {
    inner_impl(const U& u) : u_(u) {}
    inner_impl* copy() const override { return new inner_impl(u_); }
    operator const T*() const override { return &u_; }
    operator T*() override { return &u_; }

    U u_;
  };
};
```