# deep copy with smart pointer-attached inherited objects

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, smart-pointers, deep-copy

I am not sure what the best / cleanest solution to making a deep copy of an object with a smart pointer containing inherited objects is. To boil it down, given the following code

```
class A {};

class D1 : public A{
public:
    int x1 = 0;
};

class D2 : public A {
public:
    int x2 = 2;
};


class V {
public:
    V(A* a) : ptr(a) {}
    std::unique_ptr<A> ptr;
};    

void run() {
    std::vector<V> v;
    v.push_back(V(new D1));
    v.push_back(V(new D2));
    /// I want to make a deep copy of v here
}
```

where the vector `v` contains both objects of type `D1` and `D2`, what is the shortest / most elegant way to make a deep copy of `v`? I can think of two ways, both with some drawbacks:

1. create a virtual `A* clone()` method in the base class and overload it in each inherited class (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24334888/how-to-implement-deep-copy-feature-in-some-smart-pointer)). Drawback: the clone method needs to be instantiated in every inherited class and there may be multiple.
2. create a copy constructor/assignment operator for `V`. Using `dynamic_cast<D1/D2>`, check which kind of inherited object is attached and make a copy for that specific type. Drawback: one needs to go through all inherited classes in the copy constructor of `V`.

Comment: I like solution 1.  Solution 2 is horrible.  I don't see a better solution.

Comment: I've been experimenting with deep-copyable `std::unique_ptr`  wrapper some time ago, it might be useful for you: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/197579/deep-copyable-unique-ptr-wrapper-with-stdvisit-like-feature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1 won't require you to modify `V` every time a class is added to the hierarchy under `A`. Furthermore, if the class that is added doesn't implement `clone` you'll get a nice shining compiler error, instead of everything building and failing at run-time like in option 2.

So option 1 is better. But you are correct, it's somewhat repetitive. You must write similar code for many different types. Fortunately, C++ has a mechanism to deal with that: templates.

Using a [CRTP](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Curiously_Recurring_Template_Pattern) class we can implement the `clone` function automatically. All `D1` and `D2` will need to do is to inherit from a middle-man, instead of from `A` directly:

```
class A {
public:
  virtual A* clone() const = 0;
  virtual ~A() = default;
};

template<class C>
struct AClone : A {
  A* clone() const override {
    return new C(*static_cast<C const*>(this));
  }
};

class D1 : public AClone<D1> {
public:
    int x1 = 0;
};

class D2 : public AClone<D2> {
public:
    int x2 = 2;
};
```

The above is using raw pointers, and would probably be improved by returning a `unique_ptr` instead, but that's the idea boiled down for brevity.

One can also add a bit of defensive programming to this `clone` function.

```
static_assert(std::is_convertible<C*, A*>::value,"");
static_assert(std::is_convertible<C*, AClone*>::value,"");
// These two check `C` is derived unambiguasly from `A` via this specialization

assert(typeid(C) == typeid(*this));
// Check the most derived type is as expected, suggested by Deduplicator
```

And you can see it live, [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e6ef05ba08a3f78).

Comment: For best effect, add `assert(typeid(C) == typeid(*this));` to `AClone::clone()`.

Comment: @Deduplicator - That would always be false. `typeid(*this)` is `AClone<C>`

Comment: @Deduplicator - Right. Brain fart, I had another piece of code on my mind. That's not a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's look at it:

1. `A` doesn't have a virtual dtor, so `V`'s dtor invokes UB when the member-`unique_ptr` tries to polymorphically destroy ist pointee.
2. `dynamic_cast` can only be used to check the most-derived type if that is effectively `final`, and the source-type has virtual methods and/or bases. While you don't seem to derive from `D1` and/or `D2`, there's nothing stopping anyone else from doing so. And you don't have any virtual bases or methods.
   At least use `typeid` instead and add a virtual dtor.
3. Using virtual `.clone()` allows you to omit all the tedious and error-prone type-checks, and contains any necessary change when extending to the new class. The alternative is registering it with a map, storing a pointer to a clone-method alongside, or writing it all out as code.