# C++ Wrapper for simple heap allocation that copies?

Tags: c++, std, option-type, smart-pointers

I am looking for some form of memory management wrapper, that does simply make a copy of everything managed, when its copy constructor/assignment is called.

I am writing on an an octree with fixed degree of 8, therefore a node is either a leaf, or it owns 8 other nodes.
So I need an optionally allocated `array<Node, 8>`. When the tree is copied (via copy constructor/assignment) I'd want there to be a deep copy.
I cant seem to find any wrapper that does this for me.
If I accept that, I seem to have 2 basic options:

1. I could do it the long way, implement the deep copy specificly in a custom copy constructor somehow, which would lead to implicit move constructors and such to be deleted and those therefore would also be needed to be provided manually.
2. Implement [some clone method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24334888/how-to-implement-deep-copy-feature-in-some-smart-pointer), which isn't exactly what I want, either.
3. I could do it the even longer way and implement the wrapper myself.

There are several neat types in the standard library that surround this problem, but all pose problems for my case:

- `std::optional` is not dynamically allocated, which in a tree structure would recursively cause the node type to blow up in size
- `std::shared_ptr` does not copy the content, only the reference. I would therefore have to specify a deep copy in some custom copy constructor of the type that uses it
- `std::unique_ptr` is not copyable itself, again a custom copy constructor would be needed

These all provide some subset of the features I seek.

Now, I'd like to keep it simple, clean and not explicit. Are there any suggestions? Features I have missed? It seems weird, we have a pointer that implies strict only move ownership, and one that implies shared ownership, but not the basic case of simple by value copy semantics.

For curiosity if not provided by the standard library: Do any of the other common c++ libraries provide this?
I've found [this implementation](https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/algorithms/general/article.php/c10407/Clone-Smart-Pointer-cloneptr.htm#page-2), one simple headerfile, which seems fitting. If no fitting suggestions come in, I think I am going to [steal it](https://programmercave0.github.io/assets/stackoverflow_memes/so_meme4.jpg).

Comment: `std::vector` ? Can hold `8` or `0` optionally

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 true, I have ruled vector out for another criterium and then not considered that option as I wanted the profile of one node to as small as possible. For me a `vector` of ints is 24 bytes big, which sadly cannot beat the aggregate `array<int, 8>`, or its pointer.

Comment: Maybe something like `indirect_value` as in https://github.com/jbcoe/indirect_value might be of use here?

Comment: @Kerrek SB seems to provide the functionality by wrapping in `unique_ptr` and seems to be simpler and more official than what I have found, thanks !

Answer (score -1):

It should be sufficient to implement a copy constructor and copy assignment for `Node`. Copying a `std::array` will copy each element of the array into the new array. We can write `Node`'s copy constructor to leverage this to perform a deep copy. This is effectively option 1, but it's not as complicated as one might think:

```cpp
struct Node {
    Node(int v) : val(v) {}
    Node(int v, std::unique_ptr<std::array<Node, 8>> c) : val(v), children(std::move(c)) {}
    
    Node(const Node& n) : val(n.val) {
        if (n.children) {
            children = std::make_unique<std::array<Node, 8>>(*n.children);
        }
    }
    
    Node& operator=(const Node& other) {
        if (this != &other) {
            val = other.val;
            children = nullptr;
            if (other.children) {
                children = std::make_unique<std::array<Node, 8>>(*other.children);
            }
        }
    }

    int val;
    std::unique_ptr<std::array<Node, 8>> children;
};
```

Comment: Yes, you can implement these yourself. Your example lacks the move-constructor you implicitly deleted by providing copy. Also, should you ever add another member to the Node, say for metrics, you'd also have to maintain that in all of them.
I'm not saying that this is hard, but tideous. I am saying that this is what the wrappers are for.